# Woocommerce: Manually sort cart items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce mainly as a cost calculation tool. Currently the shopping cart shows all cart item in the order I have added them to the cart. It would be nice to **let the user change the cart item order on cart page** (frontend).

Possible solutions could be:

a) Make the cart items drag&drop able.

b) Add another row to the cart table with little arrow icons (move item up / down)

c) Add another row to the cart table with a number that indicates the position in the shopping cart. By editing these numbers and updating the cart the user could change the order of items.

Any ideas how to do this? Onyone knows a plugin for that?

I am a desinger (with basic PHP skills) - code snippets would be highly appreciated.

Thanks very much for your help! 
Cheers, Matt

Comment: Be aware, you'll have to store the line item's order information in some way. Most durable solution would likely involve persisting it to the database.

Comment: @ Cameron Hurd: Do you know where the users cart content information is stored per default? Somewhere in his browser cache I guess? There must be an information there that defines the order, right? Any chance that we can manipulate that information, e.g. via JS?

Comment: Hey @ARaction – I believe that "cart content information" is stored in the DB, actually. `wp_woocommerce_sessions` as of 2.5. https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/10/07/new-session-handler-in-2-5/